# Convert Time Series Data to Events Based on Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL server dataset which looks like the following

```
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| RowID | SensorTime          | SensorId | Reading |  |
+=======+=====================+==========+=========+==+
| 1     | 6/22/2020   0:00:06 | S1       | 5000    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 2     | 6/22/2020   0:00:12 | S1       | 5001    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 3     | 6/22/2020   0:00:19 | S1       | 5001    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 4     | 6/22/2020   0:00:25 | S1       | 5000    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 5     | 6/22/2020   0:06:54 | S1       | 5401    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 6     | 6/22/2020   0:07:00 | S1       | 5401    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 7     | 6/22/2020   0:00:19 | S4       | 5001    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 8     | 6/22/2020   0:00:25 | S4       | 5000    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 9     | 6/22/2020   0:00:36 | S2       | 5842    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 10    | 6/22/2020   0:00:42 | S2       | 5137    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 11    | 6/22/2020   0:00:49 | S2       | 5402    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 12    | 6/22/2020   0:17:32 | S2       | 5001    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 13    | 6/22/2020   0:17:39 | S2       | 5000    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 14    | 6/22/2020   0:17:45 | S2       | 5001    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 15    | 6/22/2020   0:00:49 | S2       | 5402    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 16    | 6/22/2020   0:00:06 | S3       | 5000    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 17    | 6/22/2020   0:00:12 | S3       | 5000    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 18    | 6/22/2020   0:00:18 | S3       | 5000    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 19    | 6/22/2020   0:04:53 | S3       | 5347    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
| 20    | 6/22/2020   0:04:59 | S3       | 5566    |  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+--+
```

Which is a set of sensor readings each tagged with a timestamp.

Based off the reading changing over time I would like to create events with start and end times based off the read times

Required output:

```
+-------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| Event | SensorId | Start Event         | End Event           |  |
+=======+==========+=====================+=====================+==+
| 1     | S1       | 6/22/2020   0:00:06 | 6/22/2020   0:00:25 |  |
+-------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| 2     | S1       | 6/22/2020   0:06:54 | 6/22/2020   0:07:00 |  |
+-------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| 3     | S4       | 6/22/2020   0:00:19 | 6/22/2020   0:00:25 |  |
+-------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| 4     | S2       | 6/22/2020   0:00:36 | 6/22/2020   0:00:49 |  |
+-------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| 5     | S2       | 6/22/2020   0:17:32 | 6/22/2020   0:17:45 |  |
+-------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| 6     | S2       | 6/22/2020   0:00:49 | 6/22/2020   0:00:49 |  |
+-------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| 7     | S3       | 6/22/2020   0:00:06 | 6/22/2020   0:00:18 |  |
+-------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| 8     | S3       | 6/22/2020   0:04:53 | 6/22/2020   0:04:59 |  |
+-------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
```

So far I have attempted to use the LAG function to determine the previous sensor reading:

```
Select 
  *, 
  LAG(EVENTType, 1) OVER (
    ORDER BY 
      RowID
  ) PrevEvent 
from 
  (
    Select 
      RowID, 
      SensorTime, 
      SensorId, 
      Param, 
      Reading, 
      CASE when Reading BETWEEN 500 
      AND 501 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EVENTType 
    from 
      SensorReadings
  )
```

Could a cursor work for this?

Comment: Please do not post images of tables or data. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952). There's a link to a tool there to help with creating tables as ascii.

Comment: I do not understand your result of eventnumber 3. There's is no time for S1/5001 at 0:25, so why is that an "End Event"?

Comment: Thanks Scratte, question updated.

Comment: Error in the tables, updated

Comment: If you want to calculate durations, you need to use `LAG(SensorTime)` not `LAG(EventType)`.  A cursor would do what LAG does at best but work far slower.

Comment: what you ask is a common SQL problem called `gaps and islands`. In this case you're trying to identify the "island" of each event and get the MIN and MAX SensorTime in that island. If start/stop events aren't duplicated, you can just use LAG(SensorTime). If there's a chance that multiple `start` or `stop` events can appear, you need to first map them to a type like you did, then identify the "islands" defined by the start and end type

Comment: Yes @PanagiotisKanavos thank you. In this case however the durations are not important, the summary is

Comment: @KenAdam Why did you remove your SQL-query? It's always helpful to post your attempt and the actual results and explain how it's not your desired result. At present, your Question reads more like a jira-ticket, than a Question.

Comment: Whoops @Scratte my mistake, added it back. Apologies

Comment: Add back the query - that LAG *can* be used to detect island changes. Also add table schema and data as scripts, so people can go straight to trying to solve the problem instead of typing the data. Also check [Introduction to Gaps and Islands Analysis](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-gaps-and-islands-analysis/) which shows how different analytic functions, not just LAG, can be used to solve different problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I believe there are a lot of fiddles that take ascii tables as input directly. Some of those are also in the link I provided.

Comment: For example, a common technique in that article is to emit an "island id" which can be used to group records by it, and calculate MIN(SensorTime) and MAX(Sensortime)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the events are based on the Readings rather than the time difference between readings (although looking at the above data set I can see why there would be such an assumption), would gaps and islands still apply here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below solution is bit unusual but you can try as alternative of CURSOR( of course you can solve this using cursor)

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0eb4c52b627c85449d8c37d42bc97724)

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN reading IN (5000,5001) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END GRP
FROM your_table
),

CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ( 
        SELECT MAX(rowid) 
        FROM CTE B 
        WHERE B.rowid BETWEEN A.rowid
        AND 
        (
            ISNULL
            (
                (
                    SELECT MIN(rowid) - 1
                    FROM CTE C 
                    WHERE C.rowid > A.rowid
                    AND C.GRP <> A.GRP
                ),
                (
                    SELECT MAX(rowid) 
                    FROM CTE D
                    WHERE D.rowid >= A.rowid
                )
            )
        ) 
    ) GRP2
    FROM CTE A
)


SELECT sensorid,
MIN(sensortime) StartEvent,
MAX(sensortime) EndEvent
FROM CTE2
GROUP BY GRP2,sensorid
```

Comment: You are most welcome @KenAdam. Please also put up up vote if it really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to define "adjacent" readings that are separated by a gap.  It is not really clear what the gap is, but 1 minute seems to work for your examples.

You can do this using a `lag()` to determine the previous timestamps and determine where a new grouping starts.  Then a cumulative sum of the starts is what you need for aggregation:

```
select sensorid, min(sensortime), max(sensortime)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_sensortime >= dateadd(minute, -1, sensortime) then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by sensorid order by sensortime) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(sensortime) over (partition by sensorid order by sensortime) as prev_sensortime
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by sensorid, grp;
```

If you need an event number as well:

```
row_number() over (order by min(sensortime))
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this in addition to the solution presented by @mkRabbani

Comment: This solution only takes into account the sensor times and not the readings which need to be between 500 and 501 to be a separate event. this could be useful for other circumstances though so thank you

Comment: @KenAdam . . . As the first sentence in the answer states, your question does not clarify the definition of the groupings.  My speculation is that it is based on time.

Answer (score 0):

Why do we need a cursor? We don't need a cursor.

```
with
  a as (
    select
      case when reading in(5000, 5001)
        then sum(case when reading not in(5000, 5001) then 1 else 0 end) over(
               order by sensortime rows unbounded preceding
             )
        else sum(case when reading in(5000, 5001) then -1 else 0 end) over(
               order by rowid rows unbounded preceding
             )
      end as gr,
      *
    from sensors
  )
select
  sensorid,
  min(sensortime) as evt_start,
  max(sensortime) as evt_end
from a
group by gr, sensorid
order by sensorid, evt_start;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8cbcc0/1).